# Ubuntu 13.10 Driver for Lexmark c543dn

Tags: drivers, 13.10, printing, lexmark

I have a Lexmark c543dn that shares the same home network as my ubuntu 13.10 Thinkpad (Z61t). When I installed 13.10, ubuntu found the 543dn fine and automatically installed would appeared to be a generic printer driver. Problem is that whenever I try to print anything, the computer becomes slow and unresponsive and in many instances, I need to do a hard reboot to recover. And the printing process takes forever. I went to the Lexmark website and the only driver that they had for devon/Linux (?) resulted in the following error message: " Archive Manager An error occurred while loading the archive" after it appeared that I had successfully downloaded the file. 
It appears that the print driver loaded by ubuntu is in conflict with the OS and that is causing the processor being taken over and the slow printing.
Appreciate any suggestions to resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the installation asks you to select a driver, select the PPD option, not the 'generic' driver or 'library of printers'.

Instead choose the file from within the PPD folder which can be downloaded from Lexmark's support site.

That's what I did and printing is fast and I can also access my printer through the browser.

If you have any problems downloading the file, let me know and I can email it.
It's only 134 kb

All the best

Steve